# Cannot copy Retrofit generated RealmObject to Realm: IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, realm, illegalargumentexception, retrofit2

I'm using a combination of Realm (0.88.2) and Retrofit 2 to retrieve some objects. When I try to copy/update the objects to my realm with "copyToRealmOrUpdate", an IllegalArgumentException is thrown, with message "Cannot copy an object from another Realm instance".

The onResponse of my Retrofit call:

```
    public void onResponse(Call<List<Werkbon>> call, Response<List<Werkbon>> response) {
        if (response.isSuccess()){
            Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            realm.beginTransaction();
            realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(response.body());
            realm.commitTransaction();
            realm.close();
        }
    }
```

*I've also tried this with a for loop over the response.body(), trying to add the objects one by one, resulting in the same error/message.*

And the error thrown:

```
03-21 15:32:25.754 27465-27465 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.vl.test, PID: 27465
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot copy an object from another Realm instance.
    at io.realm.RealmList.copyToRealmIfNeeded(RealmList.java:246)
    at io.realm.RealmList.add(RealmList.java:181)
    at io.realm.WerkbonRealmProxy.copy(WerkbonRealmProxy.java:732)
    at io.realm.WerkbonRealmProxy.copyOrUpdate(WerkbonRealmProxy.java:696)
    at io.realm.DefaultRealmModuleMediator.copyOrUpdate(DefaultRealmModuleMediator.java:330)
    at io.realm.Realm.copyOrUpdate(Realm.java:1395)
    at io.realm.Realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(Realm.java:765)
    at io.realm.Realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(Realm.java:814)
    at com.example.app.datamodel.werkbon.Werkbon$1.onResponse(Werkbon.java:81)
    at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:66)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

**Questions: Why is this error thrown, and how can I get these objects into my realm?**

Comment: Some elements in your `Werkbon.RealmList` are managed by another Realm, and you cannot copy a RealmObject which is created/managed from another thread to current Realm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Answering my own question, with help from [beeender](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1396606/beeender) in the comments.*

My `Werkbon` object contained a `RealmList` of `RealmLong` objects. A RealmLong is simply a container for a long value.

In Retrofit, I added a TypeAdapter to convert `longs` to these `RealmLongs`. In this adapter, I already added the RealmLong to the realm, as such:

```
    mGson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(RealmLong.class, new RealmLongDeserializer())
            ...
            .create()
```

and the TypeAdapter itself, where the RealmLongs are added to a realm:

```
// Don't copy this, wrong version! Scroll down for correct TypeAdapter
private class RealmLongDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<RealmLong> {

    @Override
    public RealmLong deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type typeOF,
                            JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        realm.beginTransaction();
        RealmLong rl = realm.createObject(RealmLong.class);
        rl.setVal(jsonElement.getAsLong());
        realm.commitTransaction();
        realm.close();
        return rl;
    }
}
```

However, I did not have to add this to the Realm yet, as the `copyToRealmOrUpdate` function of the `Werkbon` already does this in the later stage. The TypeAdapter thus could just be as follows:

```
private class RealmLongDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<RealmLong> {

    @Override
    public RealmLong deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type typeOF,
                            JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        RealmLong rl = new RealmLong(jsonElement.getAsLong());
        return rl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good to know it is solved! in the `RealmLongDeserializer.deserialize`, the Realm instance is not closed, please remember to close it, otherwise leak might happen :)

Comment: @beeender: Ah yes, forgot to close. It was in the wrong `deserialize` function anyway, but still, fixed now!